# Icon and background in customtkinter

Tags: tkinter, customtkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image ,ImageTk
import os
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("userdata.db")



Main_win = ctk.CTk()
Main_win.title("SPDBM")
Main_win.iconbitmap("D:\\python programming\\image for background\\c.ico")

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")


frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=Main_win, width=400, height=400,corner_radius=30)
frame.pack(fill="both" ,padx=10,pady=10,expand= True,)
canvas=ctk.CTkCanvas(master=frame,bg="grey16",height=500,width=800 ,bd=0 ,highlightthickness=0)

filename =ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("D:\\python programming\\image for background\\trees.png"))
#image_label =ctk.CTkLabel(master=Main_win,image=filename ,height=500,width=800)
#image_label.pack(fill="both" ,expand= True)


canvas.pack(fill="both" ,expand= True)
canvas.create_image(0,0 ,anchor="nw",image=filename)


Main_win.mainloop()
```

"canvas.create_image(0,0 ,anchor="nw",image=filename)" is giving an error message
tkinter.TclError: image "<customtkinter.windows.widgets.image.ctk_image.CTkImage object at 0x0000012641CF0610>" doesn't exist

I was expecting background image and icon for my main window and top level

Comment: You cannot use an instance of `CTkImage` in `canvas.create_image(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`customtkinter.CTkImage` cannot be used in `Canvas.create_image()` because it is not compatible to `tkinter.PhotoImage`.

Either use `tkinter.PhotoImage` instead:

```py
tkimg = PhotoImage(file="...")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=tkimg)
```

Or get the `tkinter.PhotoImage` compatible image using `CTkImage.create_scaled_photo_image()`:

```py
image = Image.open("...")
filename = ctk.CTkImage(image, size=image.size)
# get the PhotoImage compatible image with scale=1 for appearance mode "dark"
tkimg = filename.create_scaled_photo_image(1, "dark")

canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=tkimg)
```